# Resolve Google maps link into address using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet with column in which there is links to google maps like this:
http://goo.gl/maps/1FBvx

And I want to turn it into addresses like "м. Київ, вул. Олександра Довженко 1А".

I already know how to write custom functions for sheets in javascript. Now I want to know if it is possible to call Google Maps API functions  from there, and what function to search for.

Of if there is a way to do it with CSV using some scripting language like Python - also good.